# Flattening a matrix in MATLAB with indexes

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix X `e.g = [a b; c d; e f]`.

I need to create another matrix listing the index positions and values of the matrix.

e.g. The output is `E = [ 1 1 a ; 1 2 b ; 2 1 c ; 2 2 d ; 3 1 e ; 3 2 f ]`

I have been trying to use a double for loop but even if it did work, that sounds like a bad idea.

So can anyone has a better idea to perform above task?

Comment: Are a, b, c, d, e, and f all scalars?  Or can they be matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the dumbest thing I could think of  (Assuming that `a,b,c,d,e,f` are all scalars)

```
x = [1 2;3 4;5 6];
[i,j]=ind2sub(size(transpose(x)), 1:numel(x));
[j(:) i(:) reshape(transpose(x),[],1)]
```

However, I have a feeling that there might be an answer that is more elegant.

Comment: This is pretty good.  You can help readability a bit by replacing `transpose(x)` with `x'`, and rewrite the last line as `[j(:) i(:) reshape(x',[], 1)]`

Comment: @Pursuit, thanks for the advice. I like transpose more than the tag, because when one reads it he notices it easily. The other thing you said is 100% correct - I will update.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with @Andrey's answer, but because I like to find reasons to use `kron` :)

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6];

[nrows, ncols] = size(A);

M = [kron([1 : nrows]', ones(ncols, 1))...
    kron(ones(nrows, 1), [1 : ncols]')...
    reshape(A', [], 1)]
```